# No output plugins when installing cmus from source

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, cmus

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to install the latest version of cmus (2.7.1) from the source code by running `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` in the *cmus-2.7.1* folder.

However, when I do so, it seems that it is not installing output plugins. Running cmus after install returns the error `cmus: Error: couldn't open directory '/usr/local/lib/cmus/op': No such file or directory`.

Running the command `cmus --plugins` returns

> Input Plugins: /usr/local/lib/cmus/ip
>
> wav:
>
> Priority: 50
>
> File Types: wav
>
> MIME Types:
>
> Output Plugins: /usr/local/lib/cmus/op

I also had 2 quick questions regarding installing from source and cmus:

1. Do I have to keep the *cmus-2.7.1* folder forever for when I want to uninstall cmus using the `make uninstall` command. Or is there another way for me to uninstall a program installed from source without keeping that folder stored somewhere on my computer?
2. This is a long shot, but is there a way for the terminal to show a different icon (custom made or whatever) in the application switcher (alt-tab) when it is running cmus? That way it would be easier to find cmus in this switcher when multiple terminals are open.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing cmus from source,you also need to install all the dependencies.

Look through this!

Dev packages needed to be installed for libraries used for input and output plugins.
Most are not installed on a default Ubuntu 14.04 install.
Found the list of library on an ArchLinux page (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/cmus/)

These libraries include:

libcue

ncurses

alsa-lib (optional) - for ALSA output plugin support

faad2 (optional) - for AAC input plugin support

ffmpeg (optional) - for ffmpeg input plugin support

flac (optional) - for flac input plugin support

libao (optional) - for AO output plugin support

libcdio-paranoia (optional) - for cdio support

libmad (optional) - for mp3 input plugin support

libmodplug (optional) - for modplug input plugin support

libmp4v2 (optional) - for mp4 input plugin support

libmpcdec (optional) - for musepack input plugin support

libpulse (optional) - for PulseAudio output plugin support

libvorbis (optional) - for vorbis input plugin support

opusfile (optional) - for opus input plugin support

wavpack (optional) - for wavpack input plugin support

faad2 (make)

ffmpeg (make)

flac (make)

libao (make)

libcdio-paranoia (make)

libmad (make)

libmodplug (make)

libmp4v2 (make)

libmpcdec (make)

libpulse (make)

libvorbis (make)

opusfile (make)

wavpack (make)

https://github.com/cmus/cmus/issues/197

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...